# If $a_k^p \leq b_k + \frac 12 a_k$ and $b_k \to 0$, does $a_k \to 0$ as well?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_k$ and $b_k$ be non-negative sequences of real numbers such that $b_k \to 0$. If
$a_k^p \leq b_k + \frac{1}{2}a_k$ holds for all $k$, where $p \geq 2$, does it follow  that $a_k \to 0$?

Sadly $p \neq 1$, so I don't know how to proceed. If we assume $a_k \to c$, then pass to the limit to get $0 \leq c^p \leq \frac 12 c$, whence $c^p-\frac 12 c \leq 0$ which I think tells you that $c$ has to be smaller than one.??

Answer (score 1):

Use the Sandwich Limit Theorem, it is easy to show that $a_k^p - \dfrac{1}{2} a_k \to 0$. Let's assume that $a_k \to c$. This equation must hold: $c^p - \dfrac{1}{2} c = 0$. There. It is still possible that $a_k \to \frac{1}{2}$.

It's possible to build up an example: Let $a_k = \dfrac{1}{2}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b_k = \dfrac{1}{k}$. The inequality holds for all $p \geqslant 2$, $b_k \to 0$ and still $a_k \to \dfrac{1}{2}$

Therefore, I conclude that the answer is NEGATIVE.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you choose $a_k = \sqrt[p-1]{{1 \over 2}}$ you have
$a_k^p = {1 \over 2} a_k$, and as long as $b_k \ge 0$, we have
$a_k^p \le b_k + {1 \over 2} a_k$.